# Adding new object by pressing left mouse

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception

Got an array of `Object` instances (`Sprites`), got method to add a new object to array by pressing left mouse button:

```
private void addSprite() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                Sprite sprite = new Ball(x, y);
                if (sprites[sprites.length - 1] == null){
                    sprites[sprites.length - 1] = sprite;
                }else if (sprites[sprites.length - 1] != null){
                    Sprite[] temp = new Sprite[sprites.length * 2];
                    System.arraycopy(sprites, 0, temp, 0, sprites.length);
                    sprites = temp;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

If `arr` is full I create new temporary array, size of `sprites.length * 2`, and copy all elements in a `temporary array`, and change link `sprites = temp`, and I've got `NullPointerException`. Task is adding new objects using only arrays, not `ArrayList`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you checking only last index ?, what if sprites.lenght - 2 is also == null, this index will always be null, use array list instead, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

work like this:

```
   private void addSprite() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                Sprite sprite = new Ball(x, y);
                if (sprites[count] == null){
                    sprites[count] = sprite;
                    count++;
                }else if (sprites[count] != null){
                    Sprite[] temp = new Sprite[sprites.length + 1];
                    System.arraycopy(sprites, 0, temp, 0, sprites.length);
                    temp[sprites.length] = sprite;
                    sprites = temp;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If create array size: `sprites.length * 2`:
problem is java try to `update` and `render` `null` elements of `array`
If create `sprites.length + 1` and add on an last `index` element there is no `null` elements in array, it's work fine.

Comment: Don't use an Array. Instead use an `ArrayList`. It does the size management for you. In other words, "don't reinvent the wheel".

Comment: It's not "java" that tries to update and render null elements, it's your code that does. Doubling the array size works fine as long as you keep in mind that the array will contain null elements.